# (InvalidCastException): Specified cast is not valid

Tags: vb.net

I am running an application through visual studio which builds a particular project and references multiple other projects. I am running into an InvalidCastException in one of the files in the project.

I've tried to create an instance for the objEmail Object property. It did not help me here.

```
Public objEmail As TApplication.ITDocument
Public Function CreateObject6(progId As String, Optional serverName As String = "") As Object 
    'This is from a [metadata] file and I have pasted it here for better understanding.

Function Init(ByRef p_objMainForm As Object, ByRef p_objSystem As ISystemInfo, ByRef p_objDocTemplate As ITDocumentTemplate, ByRef p_objDocManager As IDocManager, ParamArray p_varParamArray() As Object) As Boolean 
    'This is the function that the objEmail appears to call and error appears.

objEmail = CreateObject6("cssEmail.cEmail")
WriteToActivityLog("SubMain Line 3.2")
Dim mainFormInstance As Object = frmTBWMainForm
objEmail.Init(mainFormInstance, SystemObject, DocTemplate, objDocManager) 'Error appears in this line (InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid)
```

Comment: You don't have `ParamArray p_varParamArray() As Object` as `Optional` and it doesn't look like you are passing anything to it.

Comment: This is a COM library, the odds that you can pass a Winforms Form object as the first argument are quite low.  It tells you that you can't with an InvalidCastException.

Comment: Please provide more information on the object you are using. What is `cssEmail.cEmail`? Provide a link to some information/documentation on it.